# How to compare values between string and BigInteger in java

Tags: java

```
String str="1234";
String str2="1234";
BigInteger bigInt=new BigInteger("1234");
Object v1=str;
Object v2=str2;
Object v3=bigInt;
System.out.println("Condition1==>>"+v1.equals(v2));
System.out.println("Condition2==>>"+v1.equals(v3));`
```

Output:

```
Condition1==>>true

Condition2==>>false
```

Why the second condition( v1.equals(v3) ) result is false even though the values are same?.What is the difference between two conditions?
How to make the second condition result to true?

Comment: Why would you expect `String.equals(BigInteger)` to ever return `true`? Those are 2 different types.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))? `for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).`

Comment: @Rohit Jain    I have a common method that compares values of two Object types using equals() method.Those two Object types are of different types which are sent as parameters to this method . How to compare the values of different types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RohitJain commented They are not even the same type. Actually the first check in every `equals()` method is

```
if(other instanceof ThisType)
```

In your case:

```
bigInt.toString().equals(str1)
```

would return true.

Answer (score 3):

You might be confused about how types work. Sometimes, there are certain similar (isomporphic) values between two types. For example, the String `"123"` and the int `123`. Although they look the same, and can be converted from one to the other without loss of information, they aren't actually the same type (and they have no pre-defined automatic conversion in Java), therefore no two values from each type will be equal.

You have to define and perform those conversions yourself. So you'd need to write:

```
new BigInteger(v1).equals(v3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply equals on the same class objects.
So you need to compare `String` and `String` or `BigInteger` and `BigInteger`.
You can get the `String` value of your `BigInteger` and compare it with the `String` or you need to create a new `BigInteger` from the `String` and compare it with the other `String`.